# ngSubmit.emit() does not change submitted property of formGroup

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms

I have two forms which validations are triggered on submit and only then are shown to the user. However, I need to trigger this submit on two forms simultaneously so that I show fields which are required to fill.

Now I have something like

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" #myForm="ngForm" ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="formAssemblyCompleted; else loader>
...
</form>

<form [formGroup]="form2" class="mb-5">
</form>

<button class="btn btn_orange" type="submit (click)="myForm.ngSubmit.emit(true)">
    Submit
</button>
```

And in component

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
```

The function that is bound to `ngSubmit` is being called as it should, however the `submitted` property on `myForm` doesn't change its state to `true`

Comment: Have you tried this.form1.markAsTouched();?

Comment: @Chellappan where is a connection between submitted and touched?

Comment: since you want to show error message you can use markAsTouched to enable the validation check

Comment: @Chellappan if you have read what I have written you could notice that my validation is shown **only** after submit

Comment: you want to show validation for both form when you click the button right?

Answer (score 3):

The question was done long ago but I have the answer. The `myForm.ngSubmit.emit(true)` will only trigger the EventEmitter that will call the function passed on `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"`. Looking into the code I noticed that the function that turns `submitted` to true is the `onSubmit($event)`. It will also emit the `ngSubmit`. Here is the extract of the code.

```
onSubmit($event: Event): boolean {
    (this as {submitted: boolean}).submitted = true;
    syncPendingControls(this.form, this._directives);
    this.ngSubmit.emit($event);
    return false;
  }
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L288-L301

So in your case you would need to do this:

```
<button class="btn btn_orange" type="submit (click)="myForm.onSubmit($event)">
    Submit
</button>
```